# Why is Vanilla JS not running my if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

So I'm making an Interchange game.

I want the player to enter an answer and my if statements will check if that answer is correct, according to an array that I have set up. It will randomize so I will use the variable that is randomized to do something like this:

```
function getRandomImage(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var img = imageArray[num];
    document.getElementById("question-image").innerHTML = ('<img src="' + img + '"width=450px; height=550px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">');
    console.log("random image!");
    console.log(answers[num]);
    const textarea = document.getElementById("answer-textarea").value;

    if (document.getElementById("answer-textarea").value == answers[num].toString() && skipCounter > 3){
        console.log(answers[num]);
        score++;
        document.getElementById("score-txt").innerHTML = ("<b>Score: </b>" + "<b>" + score + "</b>");
    }

    else if (document.getElementById("answer-textarea").value != answers[num].toString() && skipCounter > 3){
        console.log(answers[num]);
        score--;
        document.getElementById("score-txt").innerHTML = ("<b>Score: </b>" + "<b>" + score + "</b>");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class="answer-textarea" id="answer-textarea"></textarea>
```

When I run this, AND I enter the correct answer according to my array, it does nothing.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgEEk.png)

Array:

```
answers = new Array();
answers[0] = "Turbine Interchange";
answers[1] = "Complex Roundabout";
answers[2] = "Cloverleaf Interchange";
answers[3] = "High Five";
answers[4] = "Mixing Bowl Interchange";
answers[5] = "Light Horse Interchange";
answers[6] = "T Interchange";
answers[7] = "Trumpet Interchange";
answers[8] = "Vaanplein Junction";
answers[9] = "Ya'an East Road Interchange";
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

**EDIT 1:**
I've updated my code now and I'm checking for my texrarea value, answer, skip counter and current score.

```
console.log(textarea + "\n" + answers[num] + "\n" + skipCounter + "\n" + score);
```

**EDIT 2:**
Yep the if functions are not even working. I added a new statement on the bottom of my ifs:

```
else {
    console.log("Did nothing!")
}
```

It all just says "did nothing".

Comment: Your `if` statements are pretty complex. Have you tried breaking up the `if` statement into smaller conditions and then tried to evaluate those statements? For example, what is the value of `document.getElementById("answer-textarea").value == answers[num].toString()` and `skipCounter > 3` separate from each other?

Comment: Why are you calling `.toString()`? The answers are all strings.

Comment: You set the `textarea` variable to the value of the input. Why do you keep calling `document.getElementById("answer-textarea").value` instead of using the variable?

Comment: You seem to be randomizing the question after the user has already answered. Is that what it's supposed to do?

Comment: I would assume it is your skipCounter that is causing the condition to fail. is skip counter greater than 3 when you call the function?

Comment: Try putting `console.log(textarea, answers[num], skipCounter)` before the `if` statement so you can see what you're testing.

Comment: You need to provide more context, like when this function is called? How do you handle the submit event of the answer?

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky I did try to console.log() all my variables and copy and paste in to my textarea. I also tried to check if my answer (the variable i copy and pasted) is equal to my array of [num]. It returns true; so i dont know whats wrong here

Comment: I don't see any event listener for your textarea input, that's why your function is not called. Unless you did not provide that piece of code.

Comment: @essentialz you were right  But still, the score is only subtracting if I get the correct answer

Comment: @dehumanizer wdym?

Comment: wait @Barmar >You seem to be randomizing the question after the user has already answered. Is that what it's supposed to do? Yea the picture and question should be randomised and be the same after the user enters their answer... unless thats not what I'm doing?

Comment: It seems backwards. You should pick a random question, show the question to the user, then when the user answers the question you check whether it's correct. If you randomize the question after they answer, then they answered a different question.

Comment: @Barmar So I should add another function to check if the answer is right, right?

Comment: Yes. One function for displaying the random question, another for checking the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the program.

For future reference and others', here's how I did it.

1. I made the `num` var global

   var num;

   getRandImg(){//bla bla bla}
2. Separated get randImg() and checkAns()
3. Made a Boolean to check if it is the first time laoding, so I dont check for the next answer as @Barmar said.

> You seem to be randomizing the question after the user has already answered. Is that what it's supposed to do? –
> Barmar

Thanks for all of your help stackoverflow people! I've also made a repo for the project, if you wanna see the full code. https://github.com/elfryt/whats-the-interchange

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren’t actually adding the answers to the array.

You need to use the array `push` method.

```
answers = new Array();
answers.push("Turbine Interchange");
answers.push("Complex Roundabout");
answers.push("Cloverleaf Interchange");
// etc
```

Once you make that change it will work as intended.

An alternative method which I would recommend is to initialize the array as it is being created.

```
var answers = [
  “Answer one”,
  “Answer two”,
  “Answer three”,
  // etc
];
```

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work tho...https://ibb.co/TkcfLMx (I did try to initialise the array using var answers = [...])

Comment: I just realized what is going on. I’ll update my answer.